# Weather app showing wrong temperature values

Tags: windows-8.1, weather

I have Windows 8.1 and noticed that almost always (as in "as long I remember having Windows 8.1") the weather tile/app is showing strange values for temperature. It is set to show weather for my town.

For example this happened just now:

- I open the start screen and the tile show 26℃
- after a second it changes to 24℃
- after another second I open the app by clicking the tile and it takes about a second to load and then it shows 23℃
- I close it and get back to the start screen where the tile still shows 24℃ (even several minutes later)

After posting the question I also noticed this:

- app shows one value
- I click on the value (it changes from Celsius to Fahrenheit)
- I click again (goes back to Celsius)
- it shows a different temperature than on start

Is the app using different code (logic) or data than the tile?

This basically makes it useless, because I never know if the value I see is real or totally off.

By the way: I saw many other weather apps/widgets/gadgets/weblets (on different platforms) behave similarly. As if programming "load data from server, then display it" is some hard programming problem.

Comment: "Is the app using different code or data than the tile?" - Yes, it absolutely is using different code to display the temperature on the tile then in the application.  It would be using the same source for the data though.

Comment: When it comes to accurate weather info, try to take as much control to your hands as possible - external weather info gathering program that connects to your local weather station (if you can trust it...).